# Scrapy crawl entire website before follow

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I use a Scrapy crawler to crawl the web indefinitely, my script use a `DEPTH_LIMIT = 0`.

I have two principals problems :

1. My Crawler follow the websites before crawling entirely the first website in `start_urls`.
2. The crawler stay on big website like `tumblr` or `youtube` and he stay on it crawling the billions pages. How avoid this ? I can't list every big site on the `deny` variable.

.

```
class MyItem(Item):
    url = Field()

class HttpbinSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "expired"
    start_urls = ['http://www.siteA.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.com', '.fr', '.net', '.org', '.info', '.casino'),
                           deny=('facebook','amazon', 'wordpress', 'blogspot', 'free', 'reddit', 'videos', 'youtube', 'google', 'doubleclick', 'microsoft', 'yahoo', 'bing', 'znet', 'stackexchang', 'twitter', 'wikipedia', 'creativecommons', 'mediawiki', 'wikidata'),
                           ),
             process_request='add_errback', 
             follow=True),
    )

    custom_settings = {
        'RETRY_ENABLED': True,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT' : 0,
        'LOG_ENABLED' : True,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN' : 32,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 64,
    }

    def add_errback(self, request):
        self.logger.debug("add_errback: patching %r" % request) 
        return request.replace(errback=self.errback_httpbin)

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.info('Domain expired : %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fine manual:

> Does Scrapy crawl in breadth-first or depth-first order?
>
> By default, Scrapy uses a LIFO queue for storing pending requests,
>   which basically means that it crawls in DFO order. This order is more
>   convenient in most cases. If you do want to crawl in true BFO order,
>   you can do it by setting the following settings:
>
> DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
>
> SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
>
> SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'